# Как закрыть от индексации страницы

Tags: seo, индексация, robots.txt

Нужно закрыть от индексации след. страницы:

```
/catalog/?q=Стулья+офисные&s=Найти
/catalog/?q=сонома&s=Найти
/catalog/?section_id=1314&q=Подушка+&how=r
/catalog/divany-i-kresla/vse-divany/filter/dlina-to-1.88/apply/
/catalog/?section_id=1428&q=Гостиная+3&s=Найти
/form/?name=toorder&form_id=TOORDER&data-trigger={"class":"btn-lg to-order btn btn-default animate-load has-ripple","data-event":"jqm","data-param-form_id":"TOORDER","data-name":"toorder","data-autoload-product_name":"Диван угловой ЛЕО (Amigo (green))","data-autoload-product_id":"206121"}
/catalog/?section_id=1420&q=Комоды&how=r
```

Попробовала добавить след. строки в `robots.txt`, но не помогло.

```
Disallow: /*?q=
Disallow: /*?section_id=
Disallow: /*?name=
Disallow: /catalog/divany-i-kresla/vse-divany/filter/
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Обычно фильтрацию в верстке оборачивают тегами <noindex></noindex> вроде как

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте директиву [Clean-param](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/robot-workings/clean-param.html) для исключения параметров q, s и how:

```
Clean-param: q&s&how /catalog*
```

А url подобные /catalog/divany-i-kresla/vse-divany/filter/dlina-to-1.88/apply/ закройте при помощи

```
Disallow: /catalog/*/filter/*
```

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, а сколько нужно времени, чтобы Яндекс учел эту директиву? Я добавила эту строку с Clean param, но страницы все еще не закрыты от индексации.

Comment: всегда по разному